# ordenar array de string

Tags: java, array, string, ordenamiento

Hola buenas intento hacer un menú con varias opciones y el problema es que no me deja ordenar una lista.
Esta es la lista que tengo creada y el menú. El problema es que por mucho que lo intente no puedo ordenar la lista. Lo he probado y solo funciona con listas ya definidas no con listas que añades tu la información

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int select = -1;
    int num_elements=15;
    int pos = num_elements;
    int elem = 14;
    String element;
    String alum[] = new String[num_elements];
    //afegim als alumnes manualment
    alum[0] = "Florian";
    alum[1] = "Sebastian";
    alum[2] = "Enric";

    while (select != 0) {
        System.out.println("Opcions a ellegir: 
                    "6.- Ordenar\n");
        select = sc.nextInt();
        switch(select) {
        case 6:
            //Ordena el array
            Arrays.sort(alum);

            //Mostramos el array ya ordenado
            for (String i : alum) {
                System.out.print(alum + ", ");

                 break;
```

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar qué quieres decir con esto: *«Lo he probado y solo funciona con listas ya definidas no con listas que añades tu la información»*? Gracias.

Comment: Primero el código que presentas tiene muchas fallas, Segundo siempre coloca un código mínimo comprobable y puntualiza que es el error y Terceto si quieres una repuesta pon mas esfuerzo en tu pregunta te recomiendo que leas el apartado como preguntar https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Los errores son `num_elements` es 15  pero solo agregas 3 valores al `alum`  cuando lo quieras ordenar te dará un `NullPointerException` porque inicializas el array con mas valores de los que agregas y cuando el `Arrays.sort` compare los String con null fallara, los array son estáticos si quieres algo dinámico usa LinkedList para mantener el orden, en el `For` debes imprimir `(i + ", ");` si imprimes alum será el array no el String de la iteración y quien sabe quemas hay ya que veo un `break` mal colocado dentro de los corchetes del `For` porque no esta el código completo

Answer (score 0):

utiliza una encapsulacion en burbuja, cada vez que ingreses un nuevo dato en alum ejecutas el metodo de ordenado en burbuja que permite como su nombre indica ordenar datos en orden alfabetico, mira esta clase y modificala con respecto a la tuya, si estas usando array fijos sirve esta, si no son fijos utiliza un ArrayList y modifica la clase con respecto al ArrayList.

```
import java.util.*;
public class clasesita {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       // Valores que tiene el array A desordenado.
        Scanner tecla = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
        int tam;
        System.out.println("ingrese tamaño");
        tam = tecla.nextInt();
        String[] A= new String[tam]; 
        for(int i=0; i<A.length; i++) 
        {
            System.out.println("ingrese texto: "+i);
            A[i] = key.nextLine();
        }

        // Imprimimos el array A desordenado. 
        System.out.println("array A desordenado: "); 
        for(int i=0; i<A.length; i++) 
        {System.out.println( " A[" + i + "] = " + A[i] ); }

        // Inicio del metodo de ordenamiento de la Burbuja
        String aux; 
        for(int i=1; i<=A.length; i++) {  
            for(int j=0; j<A.length-i; j++) { 
                if( A[j].compareTo( A[j+1] ) > 0 ) { 
                    aux   = A[j]; 
                    A[j]  = A[j+1]; 
                    A[j+1]= aux; 
                }    
            } 
        }
        // Fin del metodo de ordenamiento de la Burbuja

        // Imprimimos el array A ordenado. 
        System.out.println("\n array A ordenado: "); 
        for(int i=0; i<A.length; i++) 
        {System.out.println( " A[" + i + "] = " + A[i] ); }
    }
}
```